# How to add mouse over tooltip to PrimeNG datatable pagination?

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

I'am working on a project where I need to provide mouseover tooltip to pagination.

Is there a way to add tooltips for prev, next to PrimeNG datatable pagination ?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find how to override this in PrimeNG doc but what you can do is to add the tooltip dynamically from your component.

Fist, you have to select the link you want to add the tooltip. Let's go with the "next button". If you inspect it, you'll find it has a class named *ui-paginator-last* so in order to select this link, use the *querySelector* method :

```
this.paginatorLastSelector = <HTMLElement>document.querySelector("a.ui-paginator-last");
```

Then, let's add a *title* to that link so that it will create the tooltip :

```
this.paginatorLastSelector.title = 'Next';
```

[Demo](https://embed.plnkr.co/R4GN8mYrlzKPyGxTW9rM/)